# Verifying password hash in PHP

Tags: authentication, registration, verify, password-hash, php-password-hash

I know this should be simple but I'm having some trouble trying to verify the password hash during login.

Had this in my registration handler:

```
else {
    $hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_pass, user_country, user_month, user_day, user_year, profile_pic, register_date, num_posts, num_likes, user_closed, friend_array) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$hash', '$country', '$month', '$day', '$year', '$profile_pic', '$date', '0', '0', 'no', ',')";
    $result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);

    if($query) {
        $_SESSION ['user_name']=$name;
        header("Location:home.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Login handler:

```
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['name']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['pass']);

    $get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name' AND user_pass='$pass'";

    $run_user = mysqli_query ($con, $get_user);

    $check = mysqli_num_rows ($run_user);

    if ($check==1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_user);
        $hash = $row['user_pass'];
        if(password_verify($pass, $hash)){
        $_SESSION ['user_name']=$name;
        if(isset($_POST['remember_me'])){
        setcookie("user_name", $name, time()+31556926);
        }
        header("Location:home.php");
        exit();

    }

        else {
        echo "Incorrect username or password.";

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to match the record based on the entered password, which won't be the same as the stored hashed password:

```
... AND user_pass='$pass'
```

Just get the user record based on the username:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name'
```

(**Important:** I'm just copying/pasting your code for brevity and simplicity.  But you should *really* [start using query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead of trying to directly sanitize user input.)

Once you've fetched the record, *then* you validate the password with `password_verify()` as you currently do.  (Though it looks like if the password is incorrect you don't return any message to the user indicating this.  You may want another `else` block in there for when `password_verify()` returns `false`.)